# Go binaries for concourse ci tasks

Tags: go, concourse

What are some good patterns for using go in concourse-ci tasks. For example, should I build files locally with all dependencies and check-in cross-compiled binaries to the repo? Should I build on concourse prior to running the task?

Examples of what people do here would be great. Public repos of pipelines/tasks even better.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it there are currently 3 options for handling go builds:

1. Use vendoring
2. Explicitly declare the dependencies as concourse resources
3. Maintain a docker image with the required dependencies already included

All options have pros and cons. The first option is currently my favorite since the responsibility for handling dependencies is up to the project maintainers and there is a very clear way to see which versions/revisions of the dependencies are being used - i.e. just check the vendoring tool config - but it does force you to have all dependency code in the project's repo.

The second option follows the go "philosophy" of always tracking master, but it may lead to slower builds (concourse will need to check every single resource regularly) and may lead to sudden breakage because of changes in dependencies.

The third option allows you to implicitly fix the revision of the dependencies in the docker image, in that respect it's similar to the first, however it requires maintaining docker images (doesn't necessarily mean 1 per project, but it might mean more than one depending on the number of projects that use this option and if there are conflicting dependency versions between them)